How to mock a dependency of a dynamically imported module in jest
module-a.js
class Math {
  pi() {
    return 3.14;
  }
}

export default Math

module-b.js
import Math from './module-a';

const piVal = Math.pi();

export const doSomeCalc = (a) => {
  return piVal + a;
}

module-b.test.js
describe('module b', () => {
    it('should return correct value', () => {
        // I want to mock the return value of pi() here
        return import('./module-b').then(module => {
          expect(
            module.doSomeCalc(20)
          ).toBe(23.14);
        });
    });
})

How do I mock Math.pi() here?
I need to import the module dynamically as Math.pi() is evaluated as soon as I import the module.

Just use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/PI, and don't mock anything.

@jonrsharpe This is a simplified example of the problem statement. I need to mock.

First of all, If you call Math.pi() method, it should be a static method of class.
You can use jest.doMock(moduleName, factory, options) to mock the module-a.js module for each test.
e.g.
module-a.js:
class Math {
  static pi() {
    return 3.14;
  }
}

export default Math;

module-b.js:
import Math from './module-a';

const piVal = Math.pi();

export const doSomeCalc = (a) => {
  return piVal + a;
};

module-b.test.js:
describe('module b', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });
  it('should return correct value 1', () => {
    class MockMath {
      static pi() {
        return 1;
      }
    }
    jest.doMock('./module-a.js', () => {
      return {
        default: MockMath,
        __esModule: true,
      };
    });
    return import('./module-b').then((module) => {
      expect(module.doSomeCalc(20)).toBe(21);
    });
  });

  it('should return correct value 2', () => {
    class MockMath {
      static pi() {
        return 2;
      }
    }
    jest.doMock('./module-a.js', () => {
      return {
        default: MockMath,
        __esModule: true,
      };
    });
    return import('./module-b').then((module) => {
      expect(module.doSomeCalc(20)).toBe(22);
    });
  });
});

Test result:
 PASS  stackoverflow/79002536/module-b.test.js
  module b
    √ should return correct value 1 (4 ms)                                                                                                                                        
    √ should return correct value 2 (1 ms)                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                  
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                    
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total                                                                                                                                                    
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.756 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

